# Does anyone know what programming language/web framework parse parameter like this?

Tags: exploit, web

While doing bug bounty. There is a website with a feature like follow
GET `example.com/lookup?users=["username1", "username2"]`, then it return users data as JSON.

The `users` parameter looks really fishy. Its behaviors are as follow:

```
users=["username"]  => 200
users=['username']  => 500
users=[username]    => 500
users="username"    => 200
users='username'    => 500
users=username      => 500
users=              => 500
users=[]            => 200
```

I suspect that it using `eval` to parse parameter value in backend. The problem is that I don't know what programming language it is using in backend.

Do you have any suggestions for this case?

Comment: You could try `users=["user"+"name"]` that should show if it's using eval, or just parsing JSON

Comment: @paj28, That's a good idea !!. I tried it, it return `500`

Comment: Oh well, looks like it's not being eval'ed

Comment: This is a pure programming question. It is off topic here. I suggest to close it or to move to SO.

Comment: could be json.parse instead of eval